# Сборка VUE приложения на production

Tags: javascript, vue.js

меня интересует вопрос, как собрать VUE приложение, чтобы в нем не было исходного кода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собираю с помощью команды: `vue-cli-service build --mode production`.
Пробовал выводить в консоль `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);` показывает, что production.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В нём нет исходного кода. Вы точно запустили собранную версию, а не dev?

Comment: да, точно. Вот на скриншоте App.vue содержит весь мой код в исходном виде.